# Completely remove VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, delete

I am running Virtual Box 5.0, and I had an Ubuntu Gnome VM in there, which I deleted, and chose the `remove all files` option in Virtual Box for. But now I have noticed that there is still remnants of the VM left in:

```
/home/arthur-dent/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu Gnome Testing VM 1
```

A `tree` analysis of this shows:

```
.
├── Logs
│   ├── VBox.log
│   ├── VBox.log.1
│   ├── VBox.log.2
│   └── VBox.log.3
├── Snapshots
├── Ubuntu Gnome Testing VM 1.vbox
├── Ubuntu Gnome Testing VM 1.vbox-prev
└── Ubuntu Gnome Testing VM 1.vdi

2 directories, 7 files
```

So is it safe now to remove this folder and all of its contents? And are there any other remnants of the VM I deleted left behind that I can remove?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

**Package Information:**

```
virtualbox-5.0:
  Installed: 5.0.0-101573~Ubuntu~trusty
  Candidate: 5.0.0-101573~Ubuntu~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.0-101573~Ubuntu~trusty 0
        500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ vivid/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove the folder with that VM

```
rm -r "/home/arthur-dent/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu Gnome Testing VM 1"
```

Comment: Are there any other configuration files etc that are associated with that VM anywhere else that I should remove that you know of?

Comment: They are inside that directory.